# Most compact/pythonic way to check if dictionary value is not an int, or if int(value) is not valid positive integer

Tags: python

I am handling messy data, and I need to find any data points that are not postive ints, or can Not be converted to a Positive int using `int(value)`

Here is some example scenarios

```
vardict = {
    'a' : None, 
    'b' : 3.4, 
    'c' : -1, 
    'd' : 10, 
    'e' : -5.7, 
    'f' : '7', 
    'g' : [9], 
    'h' : {7}, 
    'i' : 3j, 
    'j' : r'8', 
    'k' : True, 
    'l' : False,
    'm': '-19',
    'o': '3.5'
    }
```

Here is some code that can handle finding all non positive integers

```
for letter in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrs':
    if type(vardict.get(letter)) is not int or vardict.get(letter) < 0 :
        print(letter, True)
    else:
        print(letter, False)
```

And here is the output of that

```
a True
b True
c True
d False
e True
f True
g True
h True
i True
j True
k True
l True
m True
n True
o True
p True
q True
r True
s True
```

But I would also like it to find that case f is also False, because int(7) becomes a positive integer.

Here is the ideal output

```
a True
b True
c True
d False
e True
f False
g True
h True
i True
j True
k True
l True
m True
n True
o True
p True
q True
r True
s True
```

What I tried

```
for letter in 'abcdefghijklmno':
    if type(vardict.get(letter)) is not int or vardict.get(letter) < 0 :
        if type(int(vardict.get(letter))) is int and int(vardict.get(letter)) > 0 :
            print(False)
        else:
            print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

But this gives me

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-7c5f07bf3339> in <module>()
      1 for letter in 'abcdefghijklmno':
      2     if type(vardict.get(letter)) is not int or vardict.get(letter) < 0 :
----> 3         if type(int(vardict.get(letter))) is int and int(vardict.get(letter)) > 0 :
      4             print(False)
      5         else:

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: `type(int(x)) is int` doesn't make sense, the return value of `int` is always an `int` object.

Comment: So I guess I need to way to check if int(x) is possible or not. This is tricky because in my situation, I want to filter out 3.5, but int(3.5) would return an int. I don't want to filter out '3' because it can be converted to an integer via int('3').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def is_positive_int(obj):
    if type(obj) == bool:
        return False
    if type(obj) == str:
        if obj.isdecimal():
            return int(obj) > 0
    elif type(obj) == int:
        return obj > 0
    return False


for i in vardict:
    print(i, not is_positive_int(vardict[i]))
```

Apart from the raw string the others work

```
a True
b True
c True
d False
e True
f False
g True
h True
i True
j False
k True
l True
m True
o True
```